# Interview Questions AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Recently I have been asked below two questions in AWS interview, which I could not answer properly. Any help to answer this question in brief is highly appreciated.

1. How to move on premise data/application to AWS.Which factors should be considered ?
2. What is difference between Block and object storage.

Comment: If you are being interviewed to determine your AWS knowledge, and you want to show that you have good AWS knowledge, then I would recommend that you read some of the documentation. The [Amazon S3 documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Welcome.html) is filled with wonderful knowledge, as is the [Amazon EC2 documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ec2/index.html?id=docs_gateway#lang/en_us)!

Comment: For the first question, migrations are covered pretty well on any AWS Solutions Architect Professional (video) course. For data migrations you can use AWS services such as Storage Gateway or Snowball ( https://aws.amazon.com/cloud-data-migration/ ) and for the application migration you have to determine whether the application is legacy (case in which you will need some sort of wrapper around it to be able to run in the cloud) or not (case in which you can install and configure a server on an instance). Depending on the application, a serverless approach might also work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second question "What is difference between Block and object storage?"

As it relates to AWS, block storage is a kind of storage which handles data as blocks and logical volumes. AWS products which supports block storage include EBS(Elastic Block Storage) which gives you file level acess, processing and more.

Object storage is akin to storing unstructured data which are not in blocks or logical volumes.Example of such data include media files, text files.AWS S3 supports only object storage. Hence, while you can store files on S3, you cannot install or store applications/programs on them(S3).